# Decreasing space between commands and output in knitr chunks

Tags: r, latex, knitr

I'm using `knitr` with `LaTeX` and there seems to be a lot of space between the commands echoed by a code chunk and the start of the output:

[image]

The LaTeX code for this looks like:

```
  \begin{knitrout}\scriptsize
  \definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{1, 1, 1}\color{fgcolor}\begin{kframe}
  \begin{alltt}
  \hlstd{> }\hlstd{lda_test_pred} \hlkwb{<-} \hlkwd{predict}\hlstd{(lda_fit,} \hlkwc{newdata} \hlstd{= seg_test)}
  \hlstd{> }\hlkwd{library}\hlstd{(pROC)}
  \hlstd{> }
  \hlstd{> }\hlstd{lda_roc} \hlkwb{<-} \hlkwd{roc}\hlstd{(}\hlkwc{response} \hlstd{= seg_test}\hlopt{$}\hlstd{Class,}
  \hlstd{+ }               \hlkwc{predictor} \hlstd{= lda_test_pred}\hlopt{$}\hlstd{posterior[,} \hlstr{"PS"}\hlstd{],}
  \hlstd{+ }               \hlcom{## we need to tell the function that the _first_ level}
  \hlstd{+ }               \hlcom{## is our event of interest}
  \hlstd{+ }               \hlkwc{levels} \hlstd{=} \hlkwd{rev}\hlstd{(}\hlkwd{levels}\hlstd{(seg_test}\hlopt{$}\hlstd{Class)))}
  \hlstd{> }\hlstd{lda_roc}
  \end{alltt}
  \begin{verbatim}

  Call:
  roc.default(response = seg_test$Class, predictor = lda_test_pred$posterior[,     "PS"], levels = rev(levels(seg_test$Class)))

  Data: lda_test_pred$posterior[, "PS"] in 346 controls (seg_test$Class WS) < 664 cases (seg_test$Class PS).
  Area under the curve: 0.874
  \end{verbatim}
  \begin{alltt}
  \hlstd{> }\hlcom{# plot(exRoc print.thres = .5)}
  \end{alltt}
  \end{kframe}
  \end{knitrout}
```

The space is generated between the end of `alltt` and the start of `verbatim`. Part of the gap, for this example, is the blank line prior to the call output.

Any ideas on how to modulate this in `knitr` (without affecting any spacing between paragraphs etc)?

Comment: Might be useful: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43331/control-vertical-space-before-and-after-verbatim-environment

Comment: More specifically try those lines: `\usepackage{etoolbox}  \makeatletter
\preto{\@verbatim}{\topsep=0pt \partopsep=0pt }
\makeatother`

Comment: That did it so please add it as an answer so that I can vote for it. Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Follow the advice found here

[control vertical space before and after verbatim environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43331/control-vertical-space-before-and-after-verbatim-environment)

and add the following lines to your document:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox} 
\makeatletter 
\preto{\@verbatim}{\topsep=0pt \partopsep=0pt } 
\makeatother
```

For some more detail you can check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35734525/reduce-space-between-code-chunks-and-code-output-in-rmarkdown-beamer-presentatio/41468059#41468059).