# Reducing space between command and output in RMarkdown / Quarto

Tags: r, r-markdown, quarto

I am just starting to use Quarto in the latest version of Rstudio. However, I'm annoyed by the amount of space added between the command and the output in the R code chunk (rendered as pdf)

````
```{r}
3 + 1
```

You can add options to executable code like this

```{r}
#| echo: false
2 * 2
```

The `echo: false` option disables the printing of code (only output is displayed).
````

[image]

I am unable to find any references or global code chunk options to reduce this spacing. What is the usual R Markdown code chunk option for this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Decreasing space between commands and output in knitr chunks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34866163/decreasing-space-between-commands-and-output-in-knitr-chunks)

Comment: I tried it, but this didn't work in quarto

Comment: I have never used the quarto. I'll try later to do something.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this solution.

As you know, Quarto by default uses the KOMA-Script classes.

If you change one of them (by default: `scrartcl`) to the standard document-class in LaTeX (f.e.: `article`)  - space will be reduced.

```
format: 
  pdf:
    documentclass: article
```

[image]

Good luck ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You could imagine it as a latex document, so you can use the code from [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43331/control-vertical-space-before-and-after-verbatim-environment) in your `include-in-header` and create a `minipage` document where you specify the `\begin` in `include-before-body` and `\end` in `include-after-body` like this:

```
---
format:
  pdf: 
    include-in-header: 
      text: |
       \usepackage{etoolbox} 
       \makeatletter 
       \preto{\@verbatim}{\topsep=-10pt \partopsep=-10pt } 
       \makeatother
    include-before-body: 
      text: |
       \begin{minipage}{5cm}
    include-after-body: 
      text: |
       \end{minipage}
---

{r}
3 + 1

You can add options to executable code like this

{r}
#| echo: false
2*2

The `echo: false` option disables the printing of code (only output is displayed).
```

Output:

[image]

Original output with your code:

[image]

It is a bit hard to see maybe, but the whitespace is less.